# multiple post requests same session c#

Tags: c#, post, http-post, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm coding a script that goes on a website, adds to cart an item, and checkout.
I manage to add to cart but when I want to checkout it's like nothing is in the cart. 
How can I add to cart/ checkout using the same session?

Here is my code:

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_add_to_cart);

        var postData = "utf8=✓";
        postData += "style=" + data_style_id;
        postData += "size=" + size;
        postData += "commit=add to basket";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        //checkout----------------
        var url_checkout = link_general + "/checkout.json";
        var request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_checkout);

        var postData2 = "utf8=✓";
        postData2 += "order[billing_name]=toto";
        postData2 += "order[email]=toto@gmail.com";

        var data2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData2);

        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request2.ContentLength = data2.Length;

        using (var stream2 = request2.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream2.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
        }

        var response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();

        var responseString2 = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


        Console.WriteLine(responseString2);
```

When I do the checkout request it doesn't work and get the source corde of the website html home page

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: You code needs to capture the cookies set by the site & then include them in subsequent request headers.

Comment: I'm trying to use cookie containers but can't manage to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `request.CookieContainer` in local variable and every time you need to send new request set it again

```
private CookieContainer cookieContainer;

private void SendRequest()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";

    if (this.cookieContainer != null)                
        request.CookieContainer = this.cookieContainer;                
    else                
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();                
    ...
    ...
    ...

    this.cookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;
}
```

And add `&` to end of `postData` lines

Comment: little question, you edited it. why do you check if it's null?

Comment: moreover, Do I really need to do: the get the data_length?

Comment: I did another post i'll send you the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587841/how-to-do-multiple-post-requests-with-cookie-containers-c-sharp